# THREE.BufferAttribute: .setArray has been removed. Use BufferGeometry .setAttribute unindexBufferGeometry

Tags: javascript, three.js, frontend, buffer-geometry

Would really appreciate some help updating the webgl-wireframes library code to the latest version of threejs.

This function causes the following errors

> Uncaught TypeError: THREE.Geometry is not a constructor

> THREE.BufferAttribute: .setArray has been removed. Use BufferGeometry
> .setAttribute to replace/resize attribute buffers

Library with implementation: https://github.com/mattdesl/webgl-wireframes.

Thanks to Mugen87, this code now works for me in place of the helper functions with the original libray.

```
function createGeometry ( edgeRemoval, x_divisions, y_divisions) {

  if (mesh.geometry) mesh.geometry.dispose();

  geometry = new THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry(3, 3, x_divisions, y_divisions)
  
  geometry = geometry.toNonIndexed();
  
  const pos = geometry.attributes.position
  const count = pos.length / 3

  let bary = []
  const removeEdge = edgeRemoval
  
  for (let i = 0; i < count; i++){
    const even = i % 2 === 0
    const Q = removeEdge ? 1 : 0 
    if (even) {
    bary.push(0, 0, 1,        
              0, 1, 0, 
              1, 0, Q )
    } else {
      bary.push(0, 1, 0,
                0, 0, 1,
                1, 0, Q 
                )
    }
            
  }

  bary = new Float32Array(bary)

  geometry.setAttribute(
    "barycentric",
    new THREE.BufferAttribute(bary, 3)
    
  )

  mesh.geometry = geometry;
  mesh.material = material;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`webgl-wireframes` requires non-indexed geometries so barycentric coordiantes can be computed for the wireframe effect. Hence, the project developed the helper function `unindexBufferGeometry()`.

With the latest version of `three.js` (`r128`) the library could use [BufferGeometry.toNonIndexed()](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html?q=bufferge#api/en/core/BufferGeometry.toNonIndexed) which does not throw the above error. So this [line](https://github.com/mattdesl/webgl-wireframes/blob/bf073f8f18215dec87cb910f6da3775f1e8bfb6f/lib/index.js#L158) should be:

```js
geometry = geometry.toNonIndexed();
```

Notice that `setArray()` was removed because it was possible to use this method to resize buffer attributes. This workflow is not supported anymore since buffer attributes are considered to have a fixed size (for performance reasons). So if you want to resize buffer data, create a new geometry with new buffer attributes.

Comment: Awesome, thanks Mugen, I will update the qeustion will the full code I can now use